# Jackson custom deserialization - can't read JsonParser twice

Tags: java, json, serialization

I am trying to implement a Jackson Deserializer to have a way of migrating JSONs when they change (like a renamed field, for example, where I would need to read a now inconsistent JSON into a consistent one).

One way of doing this would be to create a JsonDeserializer, read the JSON as the proper final class, then read it again as a MAP, to cherry pick the changes.

I can't seem to do that though, because everytime I read or deserialize the JSON, the backing Stream closes.

```
class CustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MyPOJO> implements ResolvableDeserializer{

    private final JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public CustomDeserializer(JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer, ObjectMapper mapper) {
        super(MyPOJO.class);
        this.deserializer = deserializer;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public MyPOJO deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        MyPOJO deserialized = (MyPOJO) deserializer.deserialize(jp, ctxt);
        // Custom migration would go here...
        return deserialized;
    }

    @Override
    public void resolve(DeserializationContext ctxt) throws JsonMappingException {
        ((ResolvableDeserializer) deserializer).resolve(ctxt);
    }
}
```

I am avoiding creating new ObjectMapper because there is already a customized one, with a custom Date deserializer, for example, so when I am using MyPOJO custom deserializer I want to be able to somehow delegate the deserialization in some way so it uses all previous configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
@Autowired
    public Serializer(List<IDeserializer> deserializers) {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("name");
        registerDeserializers(module, deserializers);
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS, true);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    }

    private void registerDeserializers(SimpleModule module, List<IDeserializer> deserializers) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(deserializers)) {
            final Map<Class<?>, IDeserializer> deserializerRegistryMap = toMap(deserializers);
            module.setDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifier() {
                @Override
                public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
                    if (deserializerRegistryMap.containsKey(beanDesc.getBeanClass())){
                        return deserializerRegistryMap.get(beanDesc.getBeanClass()).getDeserializer(mapper);
                    }
                    return super.modifyDeserializer(config, beanDesc, deserializer);
                }
            });
        }
    }


@Component
public class MigrationDeserializer {

    @Autowired
    private MigratorRegistry migratorRegistry;

    public <T> JsonDeserializer<T> createDeserializer(final ObjectMapper mapper, final Class<T> returnType, final Class<? extends SerializedObjectsHistory<T>> historyType){
       return new StdDeserializer<T>(returnType){

           @Override
           public T deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
               SerializedObjectsHistory<T> history = mapper.readValue(p, historyType);
               return migratorRegistry.migrate(history, returnType);
           }
       };
    }
}
```

On the serializers I am deserializing my POJO into "HistoryPOJO" which is basically the same thing as my POJO but with all the fields, even removed/renamed ones.

Then I transform it into the current version.